# Declaring a $CI variable using get_instance

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to declare a variable in my controller. I had to use $CI, because not seeing the session file on live server.

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Memberlogin extends CI_Controller {
private $CI =& get_instance();
function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $CI->load->library('session');
    .
    .
}
```

But error is

```
Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '&'
```

Comment: May be this issue beacause of session unable write ,try to change at application/config/config.php $config['sess_save_path']=any writable FolderPath

Comment: I checked the folder. Folder is writeable

Answer (score 1):

Try this but not need to use `get_instance()` on controller.

Basically `get_instance()` is used when we use library, helper etc...

```
 <?php 
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Memberlogin extends CI_Controller {
    private $CI;
    function __construct()
    {

          parent::__construct();
          $this->CI =& get_instance();
          $this->CI->load->library('session');

     }
```

Comment: When I try this main page is just refreshing itself. I have problem about session. On live server project can't reach session file.

Comment: print session and check what comes?

Comment: Should I print in view?

Comment: On any page like this - print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Arvind using `get_instance` is only needed within libraries and helpers. In CodeIgniter you just need to call `$this->` so your code would be rewritten to the following

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Memberlogin extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->load->library('session');
  }

}
```